# how can i reset my chessboard if i click button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written this code but I do not know how to reset the chessboard when the button is clicked. When I click the button, the chessboard is generated over and over again. I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chessboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" sype="text/css" href = "chessboard.css">
        <script src="chessboard.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="fn()">Display</button>
        <p></p>
        <div id="chessBoard"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fn() {
    var x=8;
    var y=8;

    var chessBoard = document.getElementById("chessBoard");

    for (var i=0; i<y; i++){
        var row = chessBoard.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

        for (var j=0; j<x; j++){
            row.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#chessBoard {
    display: inline-block;
}

#chessBoard div {
    line-height: 1px;
}

#chessBoard span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

#chessBoard div:nth-child(odd) span:nth-child(even),
#chessBoard div:nth-child(even) span:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: black;
}

#chessBoard div:nth-child(even) span:nth-child(even),
#chessBoard div:nth-child(odd) span:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: snow;
}
```

Comment: you never delete the previous board(s). you just keep sticking in more new rows.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too symple, but it's enought to delete the content of the div chessboard before recreate the second board.

```
function fn() {
  var x=8;
  var y=8;

  var chessBoard = document.getElementById("chessBoard");
  chessBoard.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i=0; i<y; i++){
       var row = chessBoard.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
         for (var j=0; j<x; j++){
           row.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
          }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcB said you need to clear down the original board before redrawing it.
Add a while loop into your code to do just that.

```
function fn() 
{
  var x=8;
  var y=8;

  var chessBoard = document.getElementById("chessBoard");
  while(chessBoard.children.length > 0)
  {
    chessBoard.removeChild(chessBoard.childNodes[0]);
  }

  for (var i=0; i<y; i++)
  {
      var row = chessBoard.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
      for (var j=0; j<x; j++)
      {
          row.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
      }
  }
}
```